# how to access POJO property in AngularJs Controller or Service

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a config property `serverName` in my `AppConfig` java class which gets value from `cloud config client`. This `serverName` value is used in `Java` classes and also in `AngularJS Services`. This `serverName` has different values for different environments.

#### My issue

Currently I am using `pcf spring cloud config` with different profiles with different values. so there is no issue for `Java` classes accessing `serverName` but in `AngularJS service` I am **`manually changing`** the `serverName` value to respective `environment` values before deploying it to respective environment.

#### My Question

Is there anyway to access the `serverName` of `AppConfig` property into my `AngularJS Service`?

#### AppConfig Java

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("${external.server.name}")
    private String serverName;
}
```

application.yml

```
external:
    server:
        name: localName
```

my_service.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', '$window', function($http, $q, $window){
    var serverName = 'localName'; 
    // for each env deployment make sure the developer changes the value to respective env value, if not the service will fail
    .....
}
```

Comment: Why do you need server name at client-side?

Comment: to call rest service on the serverName from the angularJS service

Comment: @KursadGulseven actually I am making rest call using `$http.get('serverName')` from my_service.js to `Rest Controller` so if is in local then it will be `$http.get('http://localhost:8080'), once I deploy this to qat it will be the qaturl. Is there anyway to make rest call from `js` to `java rest controller`?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own REST-Controller something like /config that returns the server name and whatever else the client may need.
In this controller you can inject the server name as you did in AppConfig.

Even simpler
If you already have a controller, that is called by angular before you need the server name, you can set a header like 'x-server-name' with the regarding value.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan's answer is useful for what you want to do. But you shouldn't need server address if it's your application server. `$http.get('api/getUser')` is the same as `$http.get(servername + '/api/getUser')`. If you need any other server-side property beyond "server name" on the client-side; then you can apply Stefan's answer.